# Play RTSP stream from stock Android video player?

Tags: rtsp

Is it possible to configure the stock android video player (Galaxy S3) to play an RTSP stream as defined in an [.xpsf file](https://superuser.com/questions/1161591/baking-in-username-and-pw-in-xspf-file)?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<playlist version="1" xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/">
    <trackList>
        <track><location>rtsp://192.168.8.108:554/live/ch00_0</location><title>Full resolution</title></track>
        <track><location>rtsp://192.168.8.108:554/live/ch01_0</location><title>Half resolution</title></track>
    </trackList>
</playlist>
```

If you have successfully performed this task, please state this in your response and any lessons-learned.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can simply place one of the url from the .xpf fileand run it in browser.It opts you to choose media players from device and selects one of them.The stream runs smoothly.